# Highcharts: yAxis title = current series name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do I make the yAxis title the same as the current selected series?

```
yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Hits', <-- this value should be based on selected series name
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value;
        },
        style: {
            color: '#4572A7'
        }
    }

}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.  It sets the title of the yAxis to the name of the series, when the series is clicked.  [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j6CRa/)

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            click: function() {
                this.chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({text: this.name});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but this does not work. Even in the jsfiddle example its not working.

Comment: For me it works.. have you clicked on series (on a chart)? If you want to achieve the same on legend, use `legendItemClick`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/j6CRa/1/